# Skipping a "Press certain key to continue" in a bash script

Tags: bash, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pipe, rvm

I'm installing RVM for Ruby with the following command: `curl -L https://get.rvm.io | sudo su myuser -c "bash -s stable --rails"`

I specifically need it to be installed under that user - and it will work, but it requires the user to intervene by pressing "q" to continue once it hits a certain point in the script. How can I set the script to just continue without having to press 'q' to continue?

Comment: wrap it with expect.

Comment: @Sirex - Thanks, I responded the issue I'm having to hopelessn00b 's answer.

Answer (score 3):

The installer options `--ruby` and `--rails` are intended for humans only, and to allow guided installation.

RVM2 will allow better automation of this process but in RVM1 - you need to do it step by step.

Single user:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
apt-get install ... # the steps shown in `rvm requirements`
~/.rvm/bin/rvm install 1.9.3
```

Multi user:

```
# create "rvm" group and add users to it
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable
sudo apt-get install ... # the steps shown in `rvm requirements`
/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm install 1.9.3
```

Comment: Upvote for developer response: But we needed automation. When I got in this morning I was told we decided against virtual environments, just using system ruby now, everything works fine and dandy.

Comment: automation will come in RVM2 - fixing stuff or adding features to RVM1 only slows down work on RVM2 - sad but true.

Answer (score 0):

[Expect homepage](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm).

Seems to be the standard "how do I skip keyboard input" answer on SO and a lot of the Linux forums.

Comment: I'm confused - can I just wrap the entire command in expect or do I need to run this as an expect file with the shebang and all? It seems every time I try to wrap it I run into issues with it thinking I'm passing it a file. I'm setting this up in the postinst file in a debian package and I don't think I can change it from a bash to expect shebang.